# How to have . instead of ,

Tags: c++

I am using gtkmm with C++ but I have a problem. Here is my code :

```
#include <gtkmm/box.h>
#include <gtkmm/entry.h>
#include <gtkmm/main.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Gtk::Main app(argc, argv);
    Gtk::Window window;
    Gtk::VBox boxv(false, 10);  
    Gtk::Entry entry1; 
    boxv.pack_start(entry1); 
    Gtk::Entry entry2;
    boxv.pack_start(entry2); 
    entry1.signal_activate().connect([&entry2, &entry1](){
std::string a = entry1.get_text();
double c = std::atof(a.c_str());
c = 45*c;
std::string s;{
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << c;
s = oss.str();
}
entry2.set_text(s);


});
    window.add(boxv); 
    window.show_all(); 
    Gtk::Main::run(window);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is this : when I type in the entry1 for instance 10 I get 45*10. If I type 10.20 I get also 45*10 instead of 45*10.20. I tried to type 10,20 and in this case I get 45*10,20 but I want to use . instead of , 
Have you got a solution for this ?

Thank you a lot !!!!

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like your *locale* is set to one in which the decimal separator is `,`. To force `.` as the separator, you can set your numeric locale to C:

```
#include <clocale>
//...
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");
```

prior to using `atof`.